# how to play video using video data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

I am getting video data from server. i am using signalR Framework. first of all i am capturing video from iPhone photo library. Then next i am converting encoding format (`base64EncodedStringwithOptions`) method. next i am sending video encrypted data to signalR server. and next i am receiving video data and decrypted and play the video data using `AVPlayer`. but my problem video does not played. but i received video data from signalR. For decrypting i am using this method. (`NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters`)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *videoFile=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:post.mediaName];

NSURL *url;

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:videoFile]) {

url=[NSURL URLWithString:videoFile];

}

NSLog(@"Video URL is:%@",url);

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

cell.videoPlayerController.player = player;

[player play];
```

i got Video URL like this:

```
Video URL is:/Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EEC96DE7-6D0F-4D80-82B8-3C24E4F6B3EF/data/Containers/Data/Applicatication video0006.mp4
```

Comment: use MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: @AnjaliBhimani thanks for your response.. i am using MPMoviePlayerViewController.. But it is not working.

Comment: what error you are getting? can you please add your code here

Comment: @AnjaliBhimani i did not get any error. but video should not play.  i mean only showing video view screen and controls. and play button etc. but if i click play button video should not play

Comment: @satya : check my answer, you are not get any error and video is not playing that is because of you may create player locally in method i think!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MPMoviePlayerController` to play video from url' but make sure that you have to declare property for that like,

```
 @property MPMoviePlayerController *videoController;
```

don't create local object of `MPMoviePlayerController`.

you can use it something like,

```
 self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    [self.videoController setContentURL:tempView.videoURL];  //here your url
    [self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];

    // close or cancel button if you want to put 

    UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-60, 20, 60, 30)];

    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [closeButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.videoController.view addSubview:closeButton];

   // add observer to notify when playing will be completed if you want to put

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.videoController];

    [self.videoController play];
```

**Update :**

You must use file url like,

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFile];
```

instead of

```
  [NSURL URLWithString:videoFile];
```

Comment: same problem video should not play. only showing black screen means video player. but video should not play. but i got video data..

Comment: i am changing like this. but still video should not play